# How can I integrate/import my project made in console.action to messenger or other platforms?

Tags: action, actions-on-google, facebook-messenger-bot, dialogflow-es

We can integrate our DialogFlow bots to other platforms. Can same be done while using Actions on Google in a simple way?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you clarify what you're trying to do, and what you have done so far and what may or may not be working?

Comment: I agree with @Prisoner - we need more info here in order to help you. Btw, have you looked at the 'integration' page of Dialogflow? 
They have many options over there for integrations with popular platforms: Facebook, Slack, Telegram, Twilo, Twitter etc'

Comment: I have integrated one basic weather example on dialogflow stated on their website to Facebook messenger with the integration platform. I was tinkering with the actions of google console which provides some templates like trivia . I made a sample of that and now I am confused how to integrate that into the messenger or any other platform as Actions Console doesn't have the integration option. So is it possible?

Template:-
https://developers.google.com/actions/templates/first-app